# AlpineJS conflict x-data with VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, conflict, alpine.js

I'm a student just learning laravel.

Is there someone who can help me to change this alpinejs function so that it doesn't become a problem in vuejs

```
<body x-data="main" class="font-cerebri antialiased relative text-black dark:text-white text-sm font-normal overflow-x-hidden vertical" :class="[ $store.app.sidebar ? 'toggle-sidebar' : '', $store.app.fullscreen ? 'full' : '',$store.app.mode]">
```

For now, if I run npm run dev and reload the page. The page appears blank.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try using *x-bind:class* format

Comment: thanks i will try.